# Why can't I print all lines that are two characters long?

Tags: python

This only prints the last line that's 2 in length. How can I make it print all of the previous lines 2 in length? This is where I am so far:

```
file_name = "file1.txt"

with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line) == 2:
            print line
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `strip()` to strip the white space from the beginning and the end of each line to get correct line length. Otherwise your code should work fine.

```
file_name = "file1.txt"

with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.strip()) == 2:
            print line
```

The line to be modified is line 5:

> if len(line.strip()) == 2: